# ack-grep show the matched files name only. Do not show the matched content

Tags: grep, ack

I'm searching some keywords among minified files.
It doesn't make sense to show those minified content.
How could I use ack-grep 'SEARCH_WORD' and show the matched file names only

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Both `ack` and `grep` have the `-l` option that shows only the filename.  You can also use the `-c` to get a count of the matches in each file.

Note that if you're searching minified files, you may run into problems with `ack` because it specifically excludes many minified files.  Run `ack --dump | ack ignore` to see what `ack` ignores.

Answer (score 2):

The standard option `grep -l` (that is a lowercase L) could do this.

From the [unix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/grep.html):

```
-l
    (The letter ell.) Write only the names of files containing selected
    lines to standard output. Pathnames are written once per file searched.
    If the standard input is searched, a pathname of (standard input) will
    be written, in the POSIX locale. In other locales, standard input may be
    replaced by something more appropriate in those locales.
```

Shameless stolen from [this stackoverflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6637894/692658)